# Encoding protocol in types

Tags: haskell

While writing some web request code I noticed that I didn't have a clear understanding of how much strict typing is considered good practice in haskell.
First off examples:

- A session may contain a one use keyFetch token
- Hawk is used for message authentication but the message hash is encoded in hex or base64 depending on the endpoint

Notably sum types don't solve either of these problems since a invalid state always means programmer error and the only way to handle this is crashing anyway. I see two ways to deal with this:

- Less typing - functions that require the keyFetch token are partial and error if it is missing, the message hash is encoded as ByteString without any newtype wrappers
- More typing - the Session/Authentication adt's are parametrized over their contained types. So `Session' () ...` is a session without keyFetch token, `Session' Base64 ...` is a session with one

So obviously either of these approaches has drawbacks. It is pretty easy to forget some edge case or handle data wrongly without additional type checks.
However parametrizing types comes with some pretty heavy usability costs. Type aliases make the code itself look decent but they don't necessarily help with compiler errors. It would also be nice to put the session into a state monad but the changing type would require indexed monads plus RebindableSyntax which seems pretty heavy handed.

This is roughly what the less typing version looks like:

```
fetchKey :: Base64 -> IO PrivateKey
fetchKey = undefined

data Session = Session
             { _uid :: Base64
             , _keyFetchToken :: Maybe Base64
             -- ...
             }

getAuthorization :: Session -> IO Auth
getAuthorization session = case session ^. keyFetchToken of
    Just token -> ... (fetchKey token)
    Nothing -> throw MissingKeyFetchToken -- No way to recover
```

Question time: Is there a community consensus on how to deal with such slightly dynamic situations?

Comment: If you have a `Base64` that *might* be present, why not use `Maybe Base64`? It doesn't add any additional overhead in the type signature as it would be hidden away in `data Session ... = MkSession ... (Maybe Base64) ...`. This is probably the most idiomatic solution for your specific case, but what is your general case where this doesn't work?

Comment: My problem is that this doesn't add any typesafety over `error "Keyfetch token missing"`. If a function that requires it is called with Nothing there isn't any way to handle it. It is the equivalent of returning a Maybe for division because the developer might accidentally divide by zero.

Comment: using a Maybe lets you define what the Nothing case means. If a function requires it is called with a `Just`, just use the type without a Maybe. If you decide to call it with a `Nothing`, you are forced to pattern match to make the types check.

Comment: This what I am currently doing for logging purposes but it doesn't add type safety. Lets look at the options. Value not required: Value isn't forced so we don't care whether it's missing. Value required&there: We unwrap the maybe or use the possibly undefined value directly. Value required&missing: Undefined is forced and crashes or we match Nothing and crash manually. See that Maybe doesn't add any safety over undefined in this case?

Comment: The type of a function that *needs* a `Base64` to work is `Base64 -> <whatever>`. The type of a function that *optionally* needs a `Base64` to work is `Maybe Base64 -> <whatever>`. The key is to *not crash manually*. If you don't want your program to crash, don't tell it to crash. You need to return an alternate value in case it is `Nothing`, or if the value in the `Just` is truly needed, then `Maybe Base64 -> <whatever>` is *the wrong type* for your function.

Comment: As I tried to say, like, 4 times before: There is no alternative value I could give for Nothing. Getting in this situation is programmer error and there is no way to recover. Of course you would unwrap the maybe in the calling function but that just moves the potential crash somewhere else. Maybe is not enough to statically avoid this crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to **not lie with your types**, and to use a restricted subset of Haskell which does not include bottom/undefined.

What I mean by this is that your types should accurately represent what a value is. For example, your function `getAuthorization :: Session -> IO Auth` is a lie because it says that

```
∀(s :: Session), (getAuthorization s :: IO Auth)
```

The important part is the ∀ (forall). It tells you that *every single* `Session` maps to an `IO Auth`, which isn't true; `Session`s with a `_keyFetchToken` of `Nothing` do not map to a normal `IO Auth` value. (They map to `_|_`, which we are considering as not part of our restricted subset of Haskell)

To fix this, you can more accurately model your `Session` as

```
data Session keyType = Session {..., _keyFetchToken :: keyType}
```

Now, `getAuthorization :: Session Base64 -> IO Auth` is no longer lying; it will *always* map a `Session Base64` to an `IO Auth`. Now the problem is how to get a `Session Base64` from a `Session (Maybe Base64)`. This is the step that will force you to have a base case (recovery) for your `Nothing`. If having `Nothing` is *always an unrecoverable error*, then don't have `Nothing` in the first place, and just crash, since there is literally nothing else to do because the error is unrecoverable.

Comment: Yeah, and that was basically what my question was about - I wasn't sure whether that additional complexity is worth it. For what its worth, [this is how I tried to use this idea.](https://gist.github.com/Tarmean/f3af813761dce27060195ebe8ccc169d).  The type signatures ended up looking like `getAuthorization :: (IxMonadState m, MonadIO (m SessionWithoutToken SessionWithoutToken)) => m SessionWithToken SessionWithoutToken Auth`.